# Range Border In xlsxwriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to apply border in range using conditional format type "no_blanks". but when applying top bottom left and right in range it's not applying and only applying bottom. 
Any idea why it's happening?

```
        format_left_col = workbook.add_format({"left":2})
        format_right_col = workbook.add_format({"right":2})
        format_bottom_col = workbook.add_format({"bottom":2})
        format_top_col = workbook.add_format({"top":2})
        worksheet.conditional_format(row_end,1,row_end,1,{"type":"no_blanks","format":format_left_col})
        worksheet.conditional_format(row_end,7,row_end,7,{"type":"no_blanks","format":format_right_col})
        worksheet.conditional_format(row_end, 1, row_end, 7, {"type":"no_blanks", "format":format_top_col})
        worksheet.conditional_format(row_end, 1, row_end, 7, {"type":"no_blanks", "format":format_bottom_col})
```

**current output:** [image]
**expected Output:**[image]

Comment: Instead of giving downvote if someone can answer?

Comment: You can check in Excel but I would guess that the conditional formats are mutually exclusive, i.e., it will only display the format for one of the conditions even if more than one matches.

Comment: Is there any solution apart from conditional format. Can't find the way to produce the expected out using xlsxwriter.

Comment: Unfortunately not. As I explained in my last answer there is no direct way in XlsxWriter to apply a border around a range. You will need to apply the appropriate border formats to all the cells at the edges of the range.